# Relations between Riemann and Bochner integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f\colon [a,b]\to Y$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. In here, $Y$ is a Banach space. Then it follows that $f$ is Riemann integrable. Through analogies for functions with real values, one should obtain that $f$ is also Bochner integrable (with respect to Lebesgue measure). My attempt is as follows:

We have to prove two things:

1. continuity of $f$ implies strong measurability
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[a,b]}\|f_n-f\|\,d\lambda=0$.

Let us define a sequance of functions
$$f_{n}(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{n,i})\chi_{E_{n,i}}(t),$$
where $E_{n,i}=[t_{n,i}-t_{n,i-1})$, $a=t_{n,0}\le t_{n,1}\le... \le t_{n,n}=b$ and $\max(t_{n,i}-t_{n,i-1})\to 0 $ as $i\to \infty$, $x_{n,i}\in [t_{n,i}-t_{n,i-1})$. Then, each $f_n$ is a simple function. We have that $f_{n}(t)\to f(t)$ for all $t\in [a,b]$. This implies that $f$ is strongly measurable. In order to justify 2) it suffices to show $\int_{[a,b]}\|f(t)\|\,d\lambda(t)<\infty$. But this one is obvious as the function $[a,b]\ni t\mapsto \|f(t)\|$ is continuous on compact set so $\|f\|$ is bounded and
$$\int_{[a,b]}\|f(t)\|\,d\lambda(t)\le \sup_{t\in [a,b]}\|f(t)\|\cdot \lambda([a,b])<\infty.$$

My question is: how to prove exactly that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|f_n(t)-f(t)\|=0$?

Comment: Use uniform continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $t\in[a,b]$ and observe that
\begin{align}
\|f_n(t)-f(t)\|&=\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{n,i})\chi_{E_{n,i}}(t)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t)\chi_{E_{n,i}}(t)\| \\
&=\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}[f(x_{n,i})-f(t)]\chi_{E_{n,i}}(t)\| \\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^{n}\|f(x_{n,i})-f(t)\|\chi_{E_{n,i}}(t)\\
&=\|f(x_{n,i(t)})-f(t)\|.
\end{align}
Since $[a,b]$ is compact, then by continuity of $f$ it follows that $f$ is unformly continuous. Hence, for every $\varepsilon>0$ we may pick sufficiently large $n_{0}$ such that 
$$\|f(x_{n,i(t)})-f(t)\|<\varepsilon$$
for all $n\ge n_{0}$. This gives that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\|f_{n}(t)-f(t)\|=0$$
for all $t\in [a,b]$.

Comment: You can write directly $\,\|f_n(t)-f(t)\|=\|f(x_{n,i(t)})-f(t)\|$